# Site navigation blink/flicker on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, localhost, jekyll

**I'm building a site with Jekyll that uses smoothstate.js for nice transitions between pages.**

But I noticed my site's navbar refreshing when links are clicked on my local machine. *This doesn't happen to the version I'm hosting on gh-pages.*

Site behaves this way on Github Pages:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uORstSJob_A

...but does this on my local machine using Jekyll 'serve':
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlkM13-cZzM

How can I diagnose this issue? Could it have something to do with using 'jekyll serve' on my personal machine? A conflict between smoothstate.js & jekyll?

Comment: If you are not getting any js errors. The behavior almost sounds like the assets are not being cached. I don't know Jekyll but I wonder if there is an option that is preventing caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your javascript console for any errors, probably not serving the correct .js file needed for that plugin to work. Or there's a cross-domain error preventing it from being loaded on your localhost.